# DateIntervalFormatter: string of format "m:ss"

Tags: swift, date, foundation, dateformatter, dateinterval

I'd like to get a string of format "m:ss" out of two dates.
E.g.: "0:27" for 27 seconds difference and "1:30" for 90 seconds difference between dates.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
import Foundation
let formatter = DateIntervalFormatter()
formatter.dateStyle = .none
formatter.timeStyle = .none
formatter.dateTemplate = "m:ss"

let startDate = Date()
let endDate = Date(timeInterval: 1, since: startDate)

let outputString = formatter.string(from: startDate, to: endDate)
print(outputString) //16:12 – 16:13 ???
// This is correct, but it doesn't actually calculate the interval.
```

But I'm getting just two dates printed out with a dash.
How can I actually make the DateIntervalFormatter to calculate the difference as I want?

The code is almost 1:1 sample from the Apple documentation  but with the custom `dateTemplate`: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/dateintervalformatter

Comment: But this is the same result as in the linked page, isn't it?

Comment: Please, take a look at the `dateTemplate` property and that I set `dateStyle` and `timeStyle` to `none`. The `DateIntervalFormatter` uses the correct template, but doesn't calculate the difference. Is it even possible to use this formatter to get a difference between the two dates or should I do this manually instead? Any options for the formatter to not to provide a string of format `A-B` where A & B are dates?

Comment: That you are setting the style properties to .none doesn’t really matter since they are not used when you set the dateTemplate property. What I meant is that the example doesn’t calculate a difference so why should your code do it?

Comment: I thought that I could make it somehow calculate the difference, as the class name and description imply that. E.g. the interval between today and a week ago is "A week" or "7 days" etc. It's a time interval

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you actually want `DateComponentsFormatter`

```
let formatter = DateComponentsFormatter()
formatter.allowedUnits = [.minute, .second]
formatter.zeroFormattingBehavior = .pad
let startDate = Date()
let endDate = Date(timeInterval: 129, since: startDate)

let outputString = formatter.string(from: startDate, to: endDate)!
print(outputString)
```

to remove the leading zero if the minutes are < 10 you could use Regular Expression

```
print(outputString.replacingOccurrences(of: "^0(\\d)", with: "$1", options: .regularExpression))
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't consider this class, I'll mark your question as accepted. This is the closest to a solution I was looking for.

Comment: A great benefit of this solution is that it respects the localized time separator, e.g. ":" or "."

Answer (score 0):

I created this solution which doesn't involve the DateIntervalFormatter:

```
import Foundation

let minutes = 2
let seconds = 9

let formatted = String(format: "%01d:%02d", minutes, seconds)
print(formatted) // 2:09
```

Looks like what DateIntervalFormatter does is just applying a standard Date->String conversion to both of the dates and adds a dash between them.

Comment: What has this answer got to do with the question, I thought you wanted to calculate a time difference?

Comment: I wanted to get a string "m:ss", I've provided it in the first sentence of my question.